# Is there an R command to find out if dataframe values can be converted into numeric format?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

Is there a way in R to find out if a value can be converted to numeric format or not? I usually do `type.convert(as.is=T)` to convert my columns into numeric and perform mathematical functions. But my current table has some values that cannot be converted. I would like to pull those non-NA rows that do not include numeric convertible characters in columns that end with "a".

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(names=c("Shawn", "James", "Caleb", "David"), a_a=c("1",NA,"bad","1"),a_b=c("1",NA,"1","good"))
```

> ```
> names   a_a  a_b
> 1 Shawn   1    1
> 2 James <NA> <NA>
> 3 Caleb bad    1
> 4 David   1 good
> ```

```
df %>%
 filter_at(vars(ends_with("a")), any_vars(!is.na(.) & class(.) != "character")
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

> ```
> names   a_a  a_b
> Caleb   bad    1
> ```

Comment: Do you need `df %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% filter_at(vars(ends_with('a')), any_vars(is.na(as.numeric(.))))`

Comment: @akrun OP is only using column `a_a` (second column is irrelevant), and 3rd row is the only one where a new NA is introduced by a numeric conversion;

Comment: @Gregor - reinstate Monica I have more columns and rows. 12000 rows and 4 columns that end with "charts". Shoulda made better sample.

Comment: Yeah, of course you've got more data. I think the confusing bit is that you have the "good" in `a_b` row 4, "good" isn't convertible to numeric, but it doesn't show up in your expected output. It's easy to miss that you show 2 columns but only test 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of options,

1) To convert to `numeric` and then automatically the non-NA elements are converted to `NA` which we can capture with `is.na`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
     filter_at(vars(ends_with('a')), any_vars(is.na(as.numeric(.)) & !is.na(.)))
#   names a_a a_b
#1 Caleb bad   1
```

In the above, there would be a warning message while conversion to `numeric` when 'character' elements are present

---

2) Use a regex detector

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
     filter_at(vars(ends_with('a')), 
          any_vars(str_detect(., '[A-Za-z]') &  class(.) != "character"))
#   names a_a a_b
#1 Caleb bad   1
```

Comment: Note that the regex `'\\D'` will only work for positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially in base R:

```
# drop the 'irrelevant' rows - ie the ones with NAs upfront
df2 <- df[!is.na(df[, grep("_a$", names(df))]), ]
# then identify the ones where as.numeric would result in NA
res <- df2[is.na(as.numeric(df2[, grep("_a$", names(df2))])), ]
```

Result:

```
names a_a a_b   
Caleb bad   1
```